# Introduce new fields in Select query based on splitting values from 1st column

Tags: sql, vba, field, crosstab, recordset

i have a select query that looks like this:

```
SELECT 
LEFT([Total INNOVATIONS / MMD],INSTR(1,[Total INNOVATIONS / MMD],'-')-2) AS BRAND, MID([Total INNOVATIONS / MMD],INSTR(1,[Total INNOVATIONS / MMD],'-')+2 , INSTRREV([Total INNOVATIONS / MMD],'-')-2) AS INNOTYPE, RIGHT([Total INNOVATIONS / MMD], INSTRREV([Total INNOVATIONS / MMD],'-')+2) AS RECDATE, [Fact], 
[Week Ending 05/01/14], [Week Ending 12/01/14], [Week Ending 19/01/14], [Week Ending 26/01/14], [Week Ending 02/02/14], [Week Ending 09/02/14], [Week Ending 16/02/14], [Week Ending 23/02/14], [Week Ending 02/03/14], [Week Ending 09/03/14], [Week Ending 16/03/14], [Week Ending 23/03/14], [Week Ending 30/03/14], [Week Ending 06/04/14], [Week Ending 13/04/14], [Week Ending 20/04/14], [Week Ending 27/04/14], [Week Ending 04/05/14], [Week Ending 11/05/14], [Week Ending 18/05/14], [Week Ending 25/05/14], [Week Ending 01/06/14], [Week Ending 08/06/14], [Week Ending 15/06/14], [Week Ending 22/06/14], [Week Ending 29/06/14], [Week Ending 06/07/14], [Week Ending 13/07/14], [Week Ending 20/07/14], [Week Ending 27/07/14], [Week Ending 03/08/14], [Week Ending 10/08/14], [Week Ending 17/08/14], [Week Ending 24/08/14], [Week Ending 31/08/14], [Week Ending 07/09/14], [Week Ending 14/09/14], [Week Ending 21/09/14], [Week Ending 28/09/14], [Week Ending 05/10/14], [Week Ending 12/10/14], [Week Ending 19/10/14], [Week Ending 26/10/14], [Week Ending 02/11/14], [Week Ending 09/11/14], [Week Ending 16/11/14], [Week Ending 23/11/14], [Week Ending 30/11/14], [Week Ending 07/12/14], [Week Ending 14/12/14], [Week Ending 21/12/14], [Week Ending 28/12/14] FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE Fact="ACV Dist"
```

I have introduced 3 new Fields namely,

> "BRAND", 
>   "INNOTYPE", 
>   "RECDATE"

into an sql query to form a recordset. The values for these New columns are to be picked up by splitting the 1st Field on the " - " delimiter.
e.g.

```
    strConString = _
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " _
& "Data Source='" & varPathAndFile & "'; " _
& "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"


strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Sheet1$]"
Set objCON = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objCON.Open strConString

Set objRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
With objRS
    .locktype = ADOLockType.adLockOptimistic
    .CursorType = ADOCursorType.adOpenStatic
    .cursorlocation = ADOCursorLocation.adUseClient
    .Source = strSQL
    .activeconnection = objCON
    .Open
    .movelast
    .movefirst

  Stop
    strSQL = "SELECT "
    For Each fld In .Fields
        If InStr(1, fld.Name, "INNOVATIONS") > 0 Then

            strFieldValue = fld.Name

            --strSQL = strSQL & "[" & fld.Name & "], "
            strSQL = strSQL & " LEFT([" & strFieldValue & "],INSTR(1,[" & strFieldValue & "],'-')-2) AS BRAND,"
            strSQL = strSQL & " MID([" & strFieldValue & "],INSTR(1,[" & strFieldValue & "],'-')+2 , INSTRREV([" & strFieldValue & "],'-')-2) AS INNOTYPE,"
            strSQL = strSQL & " RIGHT([" & strFieldValue & "], INSTRREV([" & strFieldValue & "],'-')+2) AS RECDATE,"
        End If

        If fld.Name = "Fact" Then
            strSQL = strSQL & " [" & fld.Name & "], "
        End If

        If InStr(1, fld.Name, "Week Ending") > 0 And Right(fld.Name, 2) = Right(lngYear, 2) Then
            strSQL = strSQL & "[" & fld.Name & "], "
        End If
    Next fld

Stop

    If Right(Trim(strSQL), 1) = "," Then strSQL = Left(Trim(strSQL), Len(Trim(strSQL)) - 1)
    strSQL = strSQL & " FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE Fact=""ACV Dist"" "

    Debug.Print strSQL
    .Close
    .Source = strSQL
Stop
    .Open

Stop
```

> How do i populate values into these 3 Field columns from the 1st Field
>   column (splitting its values)?

Comment: show the actual sql statement you're building with all that...

Comment: @MarcB i did not understand what you meant. I have shown the sql statement and the entire code. I just need to find a way to either modify the SQL statement so that it can populate the 3 new columns from the 1st column OR find a way via VBA to populate the 3 columns. The former is what i would actually like. Also, if there is a way to get rid of the 1st column after populating the 3 columns from its values, then nothing like it! :)

Comment: so "somevariabletext" is what literally appears in your query? And wow... you really should look up database normalization. having that many columns for essentially "the same" data is ludicrous.

Comment: @MarcB , it may contain anything...what is commonly present along with this variable text in the 1st column, will be the word "INNOVATIONS". So i have to search for this word "INNOVATIONS" to detect the 1st column..

Comment: variable/arbitrary column names is pretty much always a sign of bad design, and that many similar columns is DEFINITELY a sign of a bad design. you really should go back to the drawing board and rebuild this. all of the above code is simply trying to patch over a bad design.

Comment: @MarcB, this is the Crosstab data i get from a web application, on which i need to create some reports. it is not created by me. There are multiple such tables (as xlsx files each representing a country-category combination) that i have to loop thru and create reports.

Comment: I am not understanding. Why does the top query statement not work? Simply call that query as a string in recordset. No need to build the SQL statement.

Comment: The query string is dynamically created from the vba code as the 1st column name can be variable. The only identifiable text in it is the word "INNOVATIONS".

Answer (score 1):

Lots of things going on with your dynamic string being built.

First, you start with `SELECT` and then later try to test to see if the first part of the string has a `","` comma because you are inserting the comma automatically during your loop.  Fix by not adding select till after testing for the first comma.

Second. you are repeating 3 columns twice. `BRAND, INNOTYPE, RECDATE` if both Innovations and Fact are in the fieldset.

Next when identifying your new column you are simply using a name `BRAND, INNOTYPE, RECDATE`  but then SQL thinks that is a column name and will give you an error.  Fix by changing to `NULL AS BRAND, NULL AS INNOTYPE,` etc..  But then you probably also want to tell it a data type so `CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(100)) AS BRAND, CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(100)) AS INNOTYPE,` etc...  If you really just want a empty string value do something like `CAST('' AS VARCHAR(100)) AS BRAND`

Print out your SQL statements when debugging and test and errors will become more evident.

search for how to get a substring from a string. And do some tests on the data.  But it will likely be a combination of 
`LEFT(Innovations,CHARINDEX('-',Innovations) - 1)` will be first field
`SUBSTRING(Innovations,CHARINDEX('-',Innovations),CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(Innovations)))` for second
`RIGHT(Innovations,CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(Innovations)) - 1)` for 3rd.

This assumes you will always have 2 '-' hyphens and no spaces in it.  If have spaces wrap the resulting `substring` in `LTRIM(RTRIM())` to get rid of them.

MS Access versions of substrings

```
Left(Innovations,InStr(1,Innovations,'-') - 1)

MID(Innovations,InStr(1,Innovations,'-'),InStrRev(Innovations,'-'))

RIGHT(Innovations,InStrRev(Innovations,'-') - 1)
```

And if you have spaces just put those inside `TRIM()`

Comment: thanks for pointing out. the comma testing line was a cut and paste error. i have rectified it in the original post. The column containing the text "INNOVATIONS" is the 1st column from which i want to split and use its values to populate the other 3 columns. Fact column contains only 2 types i.e. "ACV Dist" and "Wgt Dist". I want to filter the data only on ACV Dist.

"CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(100)) AS BRAND, CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(100)) AS INNOTYPE".....this is interesting and something new to me. Will this work in MSAccess? i will have to try and get back to you.

Comment: But question is how do i split the 1st column values on " - " and place them in the 3 columns?

Comment: Yes, i got what you meant by repeating the Innovations and Fact column twice.

Comment: this is the sql query from the immediate window : 
SELECT [Total AR Foods (HD excl#) INNOVATIONS / MDD], CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(100)) AS BRAND, CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(100)) AS INNOTYPE,[Fact], [Week Ending 05/01/14],[Week Ending 12/01/14],[Week Ending 19/01/14],[Week Ending 26/01/14],..... ......from [Sheet1$] WHERE Fact="ACV Distribution (w)" AND BRAND="" AND INNOTYPE="" AND RECDATE="". ....but now i get an error "-2147467259. VBAProject. Method Open of Object Recordset failed."

Comment: I updated with some potential ways of getting to the data but do a search and you should be able to figure it out.  I always use test data to get exact pattern when I am doing substrings.  I have to run good luck and please accept answer if this works out for you.  Thanks

Comment: you are getting an error because you don't have any values for BRAND, INNOTYPE and RECDATE in your where statement.  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp  I hope you don't take this rudely but at this point you need to spend some time on sql syntax in general.

Comment: Thanks @Matt . i really appreciate your help to guide me in the right direction. In your update, you have mentioned "LEFT(Innovations,CHARINDEX('-',Innovations) - 1)". My problem is the 1st column has the text "INNOVATIONS" but the other text in 1st column may be variable. What i mean is there are many tables like this table but with different 1st column names, but each containing the word "INNOVATIONS" in them. My problem is how do i get a handle on the 1st column in the WHERE clause?

Comment: I am sorry, i am lost! tried searching, but most of the functions like CAST, CHARINDEX, REVERSE ARE tsql specific and do not work in Access. I use INSTR but need to know where to place the functions to get the substrings ie. in the SELECT statement OR in the WHERE clause? Also, where were you putting the NULL AS BRAND, NULL AS INNOTYPE, NULL AS RECDATE? Was it in the SELECT statement OR in the WHERE clause?

Comment: ohhh access.  That actually makes it a little easier.  No REVERSE needed.  InStr is same as CHARINDEX, but switch value order and put a 1 in first area.  InStrRev will search from the back of the string forward.  I don't work with access very often so another thing you can do is take one of your attempts and a sample data and open another question and more people will look at it and help you out. cheers

Comment: I know the Instr n InstrRev and I can strip them from the 1st column. What I did was while looping thru the fields and checking using Instr for the word innovations, i stored the name of the 1st column in a variable, which now I am using in the query. But my question is where do I put the substrings? In the WHERE clause or the SELECT statement?

Comment: Assuming you want all of the records you would put them in the SELECT statement e.g. LEFT(INSTR) AS BRAND, MID(...) AS INNOTYPE etc. and then make sure you take out BRAND = , INNOTYPE =  etc. from your where clause. Paste your updated code or better yet a print out of the SQL string and I can better assist

Comment: hi @Matt, i have updated the code and the debug.print of the sql. it seems InstrRev is recognizing the "-" in the date in 1st field somehow and so the splits are not happening correctly. Also if there is no "-" in some values in the 1st column then that row shows #Func! in the cells. Also the date columns show #Num! somehow. Is it because some of their values contain "NA"? The screenshot is here: [https://1drv.ms/i/s!Am1wNPJDit1whyKpgb6vP5G-vtlu]

Comment: Start a new question.  Post the query text you just showed in this one, add some sample data, and think of what the true delimiter can be.  If there are more than 2 hyphens the method we showed won't work but I have no way of knowing how to suggest to cut up a string without seeing some sample data

Comment: how do i add sample data? Do you mean i share a sample workbook? i just posted a link to a screenshot on how the output appears.

1drv.ms/i/s!Am1wNPJDit1whyKpgb6vP5G-vtlu

Comment: the data in the 1st column is like this:

Total INNOVATIONS / MMD 
7 UP - TEMPORARY OFFERING - 2012/07/30
7 UP - TEMPORARY OFFERING - 2013/02/07
7 UP - TEMPORARY OFFERING - 2013/02/07
7 UP - TEMPORARY OFFERING - 2015/06/18
7 UP - TEMPORARY OFFERING - 2015/06/18
7 UP DIET - MINOR/NO CHANGE OFFERING - 2014/05/29
7 UP DIET - MINOR/NO CHANGE OFFERING - 2014/05/29
7 UP FREE - LINE EXTENSION - 2014/07/23
7 UP FREE - LINE EXTENSION - 2014/07/23
7 UP FREE - LINE EXTENSION - 2014/12/24
7 UP FREE - LINE EXTENSION - 2014/12/24
7 UP FREE - LINE EXTENSION - 2015/10/01

Comment: i think the '/' in the dates is being understood by InstrRev as a '-'.

Comment: @sifar please open a new question we are trying to fix something that more than likely isn't even the right way to get what you want.  If you post that image directly in the question and preferably some actual text or test records, then post what you want it to look like based on the sample of data you provide. Also tag ms-access so the access experts can assist you better

Comment: Here is the Shared editable link to the sample data. i dont have time to start a new question as its early dawn now and i am tired. i hope you understand.

https://1drv.ms/x/s!Am1wNPJDit1whyRzTcKRVH0SPM4o

Comment: Sorry I have to say that I am no longer willing to assist on this subject.  I understand you are tired but this has been much longer than a normal answer and you have continued and continued to add questions.  I wish you luck.

Comment: I understand. I appreciate all your help. Thanks @Matt. :)